# Memory freeing: Assembly NASM x86

Tags: assembly, memory, x86, nasm

I'm wondering about the need for 'memory freeing' in assembly. As an example, suppose we did the following:

```
section .bss
  _bss_start:
    seed resd 8
  _bss_end:
section .text
  global _start
_start:
  mov dword [seed], 1213432
  mov dword [seed], 231
```

my question is, would the number 1213432 be completely overwritten by 231 at the [seed] location?

I.e. if we tried to do calculations later on with the number at [seed], might we find errors?

A

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> would the number 1213432 be completely overwritten by 231 at the [seed] location?

Yes, a write to memory will completely overwrite the previous contents.  There is nothing that needs to be done in between.

> I.e. if we tried to do calculations later on with the number at [seed], might we find errors?

No, any further reads to the dword `[seed]` are guaranteed to yield `231`.